# Using box2d to detect collisions, but ignore the forces

Tags: libgdx, box2d, collision

I'm using libgdx and box2d to detect collisions, but I want some collision to be detected but the forces not to play out.

Eg, I want to detect when the character collides with a coin but don't want the coin to affect the player's movements.

Is this even possible using box2d? If so, how can I go about doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want do, but if I understand what you want to do, you can create a sensor fixture type, this pseudo example:

```
FixtureDef fd1 = new FixtureDef();
//fd1.friction = 0.5f;

PolygonShape pSTest = new PolygonShape();

//size you want for example:
pSTest.setAsBox(4f / PIXEL_POR_METRO, 
                1f / PIXEL_POR_METRO, 
                new Vector2(22f / PIXEL_POR_METRO, -1f / PIXEL_POR_METRO),
                0f);

fd1.shape = pSTest;
fd1.isSensor = true;

yourBody.createFixture(fd1).setUserData("yourId");
```

looks ContactListener interface, for example preSolve

note that sensor, this is not called for sensors.

**info**

```
setAsBox(float hx, float hy, Vector2 center, float angle)

Parameters:
hx the half-width.
hy the half-height.
center the center of the box in local coordinates.
angle the rotation in radians of the box in local coordinates.
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. To clarify for others, setting the `BodyFixture.setSensor(true)`, the body of the "Coin" (in my example) will generate `begin/endContact` callbacks, but won't affect the colliding body - so the "Character" just passes through unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/22542

Read up on collision filtering in the Box2D manual:

> Collision filtering allows you to prevent collision between fixtures.
>   For example, say you make a character that rides a bicycle. You want
>   the bicycle to collide with the terrain and the character to collide
>   with the terrain, but you don't want the character to collide with the
>   bicycle (because they must overlap). Box2D supports such collision
>   filtering using categories and groups.
>
> Box2D supports 16 collision categories. For each fixture you can
>   specify which category it belongs to. You also specify what other
>   categories this fixture can collide with. For example, you could
>   specify in a multiplayer game that all players don't collide with each
>   other and monsters don't collide with each other, but players and
>   monsters should collide

Link to manual [here](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html).  (Search for Filtering)
.